# How create a log for each date in CakePHP 2.3

Tags: php, apache, cakephp

I'm try using Logging system of CakePHP, but, for me doesn't work when I expected.

Problem: I need create a log file for each date:

```
$this->log('Message', date('Y-m-d'));
```

I try too:

```
CakeLog::write(date('Y-m-d'), 'Message');
```

Why doesn't work?

---

**CakePHP:** 2.3
**OS:** Windows 7 x32 bit 
**Apache:** 2.2
**PHP:** 5.3.9
**MySQL:** 5

Comment: There's something probably obvious you're not showing, as [that just works](https://gist.github.com/AD7six/511c2151954b12c78e58) have you removed the default log configuration from [your bootstrap.php file](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/app/Config/bootstrap.php#L96) ?

Comment: No, I'm not removed the default log configuration. I need? And, in your 'gist', the name of log is the second parameter, maybe this is the problem. I'll test, anyway, thanks @AD7six

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but came across the same problem to solve and it's quite straightforward to do. In your bootstrap.php:

```
CakeLog::config('debug', array(
    'engine' => 'FileLog',
    'types' => array('notice', 'info', 'debug'),
    'file' => 'debug-'.date('Y-m-d'), // saves as debug-YYYY-MM-DD.log
));

CakeLog::config('error', array(
    'engine' => 'FileLog',
    'types' => array('warning', 'error', 'critical', 'alert', 'emergency'),
    'file' => 'error-'.date('Y-m-d'), // saves as error-YYYY-MM-DD.log
));
```

The SQL style date format will make it easy to sort the logs chronologically in your file system being YYYY-MM-DD

Answer (score 0):

Following will work

```
$this->log('Message', date('Y-m-d'));
```

and

```
CakeLog::write(date('Y-m-d'), 'Message');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can configure your Cakelog too take a look on:
http://api.cakephp.org/class/cake-log#method-CakeLogconfig

Something like that:

```
    CakeLog::config('second_file', array(
    'engine' => 'FileLog',
    'path' => '/var/logs/my_app/'
    ));
```

Comment: You need to config this just one time, and the configuration 'll be associate to first string parameter. You can make multiples configurations.

Comment: yes, but doesn't work with date('Y-m-d'). Because I need a log for a current date.

Comment: You need to put your date info inside the message of log.... like this CakeLog::write('your config profile', date('Y-m-d').' Stuff is broken here');

Comment: But for me, this is 'complicated', because: has a large data of log store per day in logfile. So, when I need search for specific date, is more hard than search in specific date log.

Comment: @PatrickMaciel so, you should use other method to save your log files, already tried use fwrite?? You can manipulate all on this method.

Comment: yes. With fwrite it's possible, I know, But I'm just wanted to use CakePHP. Anyway, thanks so much.