# How to create log file in cakephp2

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I want to create log specially for Paypal, so how to create and write log.
I am using syntax like in controller

```
$this->log("\n The payment status is completed\n", 'paypal_log');
```

in bootstrap.php

```
App::uses('CakeLog', 'Log');
```

Comment: I have no idea buddy,I have copied from http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/logging.html#using-the-default-filelog-class

Comment: but its not giving me any error

Comment: neither its creating any log neither its giving any error

Comment: I have same problem as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14936228/how-create-a-log-for-each-date-in-cakephp-2-3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add in bootstrap.php

```
CakeLog::config('my_log', array('engine' => 'FileLog'));
```

Comment: For this to be the answer - seems quite likely your [bootstrap file](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/app/Config/bootstrap.php#L96) _doesn't_ have a default log configuration in it.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
CakeLog::write('paypal_log', 'Got here');
```

Comment: its not creating any log file